# git submit of a fix is bypassing azure devops items rules

Tags: git, azure, devops, commit

i defined rules on a bug that when status is change to resolve than a developer must add the "completed work" on that bug and also fill the "resolved reason", the fields are defined as mandatory for this status change.
on the ui it works correctly but when a developer use git commit with this command :

git commit -m "fix #123"

it changes the bug status to resolved even due the rules were not filed with data, i assume that the api does not enforce it.
can someone suggest a way to solve it - block the azure api to accept it if those rules are not filed.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid it isn't possible. Im not sure, but what i see in Azure DevOps (My team also using this tool) and othets Microsoft soft (for example Mycrosoft Dynamics, theres are very simaly functions), that required field is tracted only by frontend form.

Maybe its problem with your developers? After close/resolved task they should insert necessary information to the bug/task?

Comment: i think it is strange that rules validation is done only on the front end and not implemented on the api on a service like this